# How to compare date in JSON data using jmespath?

Tags: javascript, json, jmespath

I have one JSON data, which contains date like `jan 23,2018`.

How can I compare JSON data date with the current date?

```
[
  {
    "id": "user_1",
    "date": "jan 23, 2019"
  },
  {
    "id": "user_2",
    "date": "mar 3, 2017"
  },
  {
    "id": "user_3",
    "date": "feb 23, 2019"
  }
]
```

How can I get data which has the date is more than current date using [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/)?

Comment: Why you need this in `Jamespath` itself?

Comment: I am also interested in an answer. For cloud access, I must use a CLI tool which only allows filtering by jmespath expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMESPath Custom functions to achieve that. You'll need to convert your date to epoch in order to compare the dates because JMESPath doesn't understand date object.

You can refer an example here under Custom function section: https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/

I created my own custom function to check whether a past date has surpassed current time by atleast certain amount of seconds. Here's my code:

```
from jmespath import functions
import time

class CustomFunctions(functions.Functions):

    # the function name should always have a prefix of _func_ for it to be considered
    @functions.signature({'types': ['string']}, {'types': ['number']})
    def _func_hasTimeThresholdCrossed(self, jobdate, difference):
        jobdate = time.strptime(jobdate,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        return time.time() - time.mktime(jobdate) > difference

options = jmespath.Options(custom_functions=CustomFunctions())

jmespath.search("hasTimeThresholdCrossed(createdAt,`1000000`)",{"createdAt":"2019-03-22T10:49:17.342Z"},options=options)
```